# how to implement bluetooth to print via thermal printer on flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

i am working on my client's app. it has a feature to print out from thermal printer via bluetooth on mobile app and web app. it is working on mobile app, but i saw that flutter_blue doesn't support web. how can i print on web via bluetooth?

my code to print via bluetooth on mobile app:

```
  initPrinter() async {
    // Start scanning
    StreamSubscription scanSubscription;
    await flutterBlue
        .startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 6))
        .asStream()
        .listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        results = event;
        print(results);
      });
    });
    await flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        results = event;
        print(results);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: You haven't specified on what devices that web-bluetooth-printing should even work.